# provision calendar to outlook

Tags: calendar, outlook

I have a calendar in Sharepoint; I can manually add it to my Outlook calendars from the SharePoint webpage.

I'd like to either provide this calendar in outlook for all users (best option)
Or give them an easier way to add the calendar (now it's: "*click this link, then click agenda tab, then click connect to outlook, then change the name, ...*").

Maybe it's possible to have a link that can be clicked from an email instead of opening SharePoint?

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

When you are connecting the SharePoint Calendar to Outlook, there will be a dialog and a link asking you to accept the connection. Just copy that link and send it to your users, one click and they have synced the calendar to their Outlook.

The link begins with something like this.

```
stssync://sts/?ver=1.1&type=calendar&cmd=add-folder&base-url
```

Otherwise i think you need to do it using SCCM/group policy.

Comment: +1 - As you said, group policy should be the best tool for this and you can use the same stssync-link in there. With SCCM the solution gets quite over-engineered.

Comment: This doesn't generate a link like that. See http://imgur.com/a/lch1i for my screenshot (it's in dutch). Also I wouldn't know how to do this with GPO

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you already have the calendar synchronized in Outlook?